# How to get nearest int in operation on integers in golang?

Tags: go, rounding

I'd like to get nearest value of an operation envolving division of two integers. My initial function is like this, which always rounds to the lower integer.

```
func Percent(x int, y int) int {
            p := x * 100 / y
            return p
}
```

So for example when the result is `5.75`, I'd like to be rounded to `6`, but the above function returns `5`.

I tried to use `math.Round` but it needs receive a `float` type and returns a float type. So that needs lots of conversion which gets dirty whn there are many parameters in the operation.

So I'm wondering what is the clean idomatic way to round to nearest integer?

Comment: How about something like `(x * 10000 / y + 50) / 100` ?

Comment: This works for the simple formula here, but I'm looking for more general solution.

Comment: For any integer result wouldn't the general solution be to calculate it with more precision (by multiplying by 10, 100, 100), adding the equivalent value for `0.5` followed by dividing by your multiplier?

Comment: @rsp Fine solution. Until it overflows.

Comment: @Volker, obviously you have to take overflow into account in your calculation code but that is true for all code. Especially if you don't want to use floating point by way of optimising an integer calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operations are using all integer so the output will be an integer, so definitely you need to cast them to float first, then you can convert **float to nearest int** (5.75 to 5)

For that below code will work for you. **You even don't need to use math.Round**

```
func Percent(x int, y int) int {
    p := float64(x * 100) / float64(y)
    return int(p+0.5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create float values from your ints, then an int value from a rounded float result:

```golang
func RoundPercent(x int, y int) int {
    p := float64(x * 100) / float64(y)
    return int(math.Round(p))
}
```